# Cannot reproduce segfault in gdb

Tags: c, gdb

I'm getting segfaults when I run my project. Every time I run the program in gdb, the segfaults disappear. This behavior is not random: each time I run it in my shell it segfaults, each time I run it in gdb, the segfaults disappear. (I did recompile using -g).

So before I start adding printfs frantically everywhere in my code, I would like to know a few things:

- Is this behavior common?
- What's the best way to approach the issue?

I don't know if tests can be scripted since my application is interactive and crashes on a particular user input.

I didn't paste my code here because it'd be way too long. But if anyone is interested in helping out, here it is: 
https://github.com/rahmu/Agros

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unusual_software_bug#Heisenbug

Comment: try running your app in `valgrind` if that's available on your platform.

Comment: Does your program run without segfault when compiled with `-g` but not run within GDB?

Comment: Welcome to the Wonderful World of the Heisenbug.  Do you have [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)?  If so, use it.  Do you compile with at least '`gcc -g -Wall -Werror`'?  If not, get your code to a point where you can.  Consider adding '`-Wextra`' to that command line.  Did you get a core dump?  If not, re-enable them (`ulimit -c unlimited`) and at least get gdb to tell you where the crash occurs.

Comment: Try compiling with `-Wextra -pedantic` as well as `-Wall/-Wextra`, it might pick something up.  Failing that set yourself up to get a core dump (use `ulimit -c <size>` if you dont get them by default - on ubuntu anyway) and load that in gdb with `gdb myprogram mycore`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest way to figure it out is to capture core dumps:

```
$ ulimit -c unlimited
```

Then run your program.  It will generate a `core` file

Then use gdb:

```
$ gdb ./program core
```

And gdb will load and you can run a backtrace to see exactly what operation elicited the segfault.

Answer (score 0):

Does it do a core dump? Is so that load up the core dump in the debugger. Otherwise change the code to get it to do a core dump.

Comment: alternatively you can install a segfault handler and print backtrace (and hope that the bug didn't mess up the stack).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's a concurrency problem causing a reference to be freed out from under a method call that's assuming that the pointer it has will stay valid. The reason that gdb is probably masking this is because GDB only allows 2 threads to actually concurrently run. If you have more than 2 threads running the only 2 will actively run concurrently. GDB also has performance hits which could be masking this specific condition. As mentioned by Ed just make your application core dump and you can open up the core in GDB and check the stack.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this behavior common?

Yes. Undefined behaviour is the source of most of these problems, and by definition it is undefined. Recompiling with `-g` may certainly affect the results. Recompiling at all may change the results, if the compiler uses some pseudo-random genetic algorithm to optimize stuff or something like that.

> What's the best way to approach the issue?

An ounce of prevention is worth a ton of cure; learn the common causes of undefined behaviour and pick up good habits to avoid writing them. Once you've found that there is a problem, static analysis of the code is often a good idea; go through and reason to yourself and prove that indices will stay in bounds, data will fit its arrays, invalid pointers won't be dereferenced etc.